# Matlab: running all functions in a given directory in a function/script

Tags: matlab, coding-style

I'm very new to Matlab and I'm looking for some advice from someone who is more experienced.

I want to write a function that will loop through a given directory and run all matlab functions in that directory.  What is the best/most robust way to do this? I've provided my implementation below but, I'm worried because most of my matlab experience thus far tells me that for every function I implement, there is usually an equivalent matlab built-in or at least a better/faster/safer way to achieve the same ends.

I'd be happy to provide any other necessary info.  Thanks!

```
function [results] = runAllFiles(T)
    files   = dir('mydir/');
    % get all file names in mydir

    funFile = files(arrayfun(@(f) isMatFun(f), files)); 
    % prune the above list to get a list of files in dir where isMatFun(f) == true

    funNames  = arrayfun(@(f) {stripDotM(f)}, funFiles);
    % strip the '.m' suffix from all the file names     

    results = cellfun(@(f) {executeStrAsFun(char(f), T)}, funNames);
    % run the files as functions and combine the results in a matrix
end

function [results] = executeStrAsFun(fname, args)
try
    fun = str2func(fname);         % convert string to a function 
    results = fun(args);           % run the function
catch err
    fprintf('Function: %s\n', err.name);
    fprintf('Line: %s\n', err.line);
    fprintf('Message: %s\n', err.message);
    results = ['ERROR: Couldn''t run function: ' fname];
end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for looking up all the .m-files in a directory, you can make use of `files = what('mydir/');` and then consult `files.m` to get all .m-files (including their extension). At first sight, I would use `eval` to evaluate each function, but on the other hand: your solution of using `str2func` looks even better.

So I guess you could do the following:

```
function [results] = runAllFiles(T)
    files   = what('mydir/');

    mFiles  = arrayfun(@(f) {stripDotM(f)}, files.m);
    % strip the '.m' suffix from all the file names     

    results = cellfun(@(f) {executeStrAsFun(char(f), T)}, mFiles);
    % run the files as functions and combine the results in a matrix
end

function [results] = executeStrAsFun(fname, args)
try
    fun = str2func(fname);         % convert string to a function 
    results = fun(args);           % run the function
catch err
    fprintf('Function: %s\n', err.name);
    fprintf('Line: %s\n', err.line);
    fprintf('Message: %s\n', err.message);
    results = ['ERROR: Couldn''t run function: ' fname];
end
end
```

A problem I foresee is when you have both functions and scripts in your directory, but I know of no (built-in) way to verify whether an .m-file is a function or a script. You could always check the contents of the file, but that might get somewhat complicated.

Comment: +1 for the 'what' function; thanks!  One of my friends just raised another issue I hadn't thought of: protection against overloading (i.e. if someone writes a function called something like 'size')

Comment: @akobre01: if I'm not mistaken, MATLAB should use the function inside your workspace first, then your path (e.g. your current directory) before resorting to another implementation. MATLAB will issue a warning if you overwrite built-in functions such as size, however. In general, I think you should avoid naming your functions the same as a built-in one (unless you actually want to overload the behavior, but in that case, these only occur in classes).